# Cube formation and face-color identification

Tags: geometry, coloring

Six squares are colored, front and back, Red (R), Blue (B), Yellow (Y), Green (G), White (W) and Orange (O) and are hinged together as shown in figure. If they are folded to form a cube, what would be the face opposite the white face ?

1. R
2. G
3. B
4. O

As I solved the answer is coming:   3.B

But somewhere the correct answer is given as: 1.R

I'm not sure what is the correct answer and how ?

[image]

Comment: Seems like it's $B$ to me.

Comment: @Ian...explanation for your answer please ?

Answer (score 0):

The  answer  is 3B, the opposite of R is Y, **opposite of W is B**, opposite of O is G 
I hope this answer your  question.